# Django Nested Admin returns 404 or doesn't inline models in django admin area

Tags: django, django-admin, django-apps

I'm trying to get [django nested admin](https://django-nested-admin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html) to work, but I'm having a few issues and I'm sure I'm just making a silly mistake. Here are the steps that I followed:

Step 1: I did a pip install

Step 2: I added it to the bottom of my Installed Apps in my settings.py

Step 3: I added it to my URL array:

Their Example:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
# ...
url(r'^_nested_admin/', include('nested_admin.urls')),
)
```

My implementation:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include("estimate_maker.urls")),
    path('nested_admin/', include('nested_admin.urls')),
]
```

Step 4: I created a static folder in my settings.py

Step 5: I ran the collectstatic command

Step 6: I set up my admin.py in my project folder:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import MoldInspection, MoldService
import nested_admin


class MoldServiceInline(nested_admin.NestedStackedInline):
    model = MoldService


class MoldInspectionInline(nested_admin.NestedModelAdmin):
    model = MoldService
    sortable_field_name = "position"
    inlines = [MoldServiceInline]


admin.site.register(MoldInspection)
admin.site.register(MoldService)
```

I do get a warning from pycharm saying the below that I'm not sure how to diagnose as I'm setting up the class as it is done in the guide.

```
Cannot find reference 'NestedModelAdmin' in '__init__.py'
```

Looking in the referenced __init__.py I see:

```
# import mapping to objects in other modules
all_by_module = {
    'nested_admin.forms': (
        'SortableHiddenMixin'),
    'nested_admin.formsets': (
        'NestedInlineFormSet', 'NestedBaseGenericInlineFormSet'),
    'nested_admin.nested': (
        'NestedModelAdmin', 'NestedModelAdminMixin', 'NestedInlineAdminFormset',
        'NestedInlineModelAdmin', 'NestedStackedInline', 'NestedTabularInline',
        'NestedInlineModelAdminMixin', 'NestedGenericInlineModelAdmin',
```

But when I update my admin.py to:

```
class MoldInspectionInline(nested_admin.nested.NestedModelAdmin):
```

I get the same error, this time pointing to "nested."

When I try to access the nested admin by either going to /nested-admin, I just get a 404 with this error message:

```
Using the URLconf defined in app.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
[name='home']
nested-admin ^server-data\.js$ [name='nesting_server_data']
```

And when I go to /admin it looks the same as it did before.

A few more details:

I want my MoldService to exist just to be a parent for children services so I have it set up like this:

```
class MoldService(models.Model):
    title = "Mold Services"
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

I then have my child class set up like this:

```
class MoldInspection(models.Model):
    title = "Mold Inspection"
    description = models.TextField(null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.description
```

Why do you think the nested admin isn't working for me?

Answer (score 0):

In the referenced `__init__.py` file it contains the following comment

`# All this craziness is so that we can allow the classes in nested_admin.formsets`

`# to be importable directly from this module`

I guessed that something going on here is the issue, so I just deleted the contents of `__init__.py` and then imported with

`from nested_admin.nested import *`

works now!